# R Obtain unique records on data frame based on secondary field conditions

Tags: r

UPDATED AND SIMPLIFIED

I am having a really large table (~ 7 million records) which has the following structure.

```
temp <- read.table(header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
                   text = "Website Datetime    Rating
A 2007-12-06T14:53:07Z        1
A 2006-07-28T03:52:26Z        4
B 2006-11-02T11:06:25Z        2
C 2007-06-19T06:56:08Z        5
C 2009-11-28T22:27:58Z        2
C 2009-11-28T22:28:13Z        2")
```

What I want to retrieve is  the unique websites with a max rating per website:

```
Website    Rating
A    4
B    2
C    5
```

I tried using a for loop but it was too slow. Is there any other way I can achieve this.

Comment: I would `split` the data and use `lapply` to go through each website, applying your criterion. Help us, energy efficient people, by providing a reproducible example and expected result.

Comment: Thanks Roman! I update my question and made it more specific. Could you give me an example of how split can be combined with lapply to get the desired outcome?

Comment: I think the `split` and `lapply` idea that @RomanLuštrik was mentioning is along the lines of what DWin had in his answer. Also, see the updates to my answer for matching *all* rows that meet your condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably explore the `data.table` package, though without more details, the following example solution is *most likely* ***not*** *going to be what you need*. I mention this because, in particular, there might be more than one "Rating" record per group which matches `max`; how would you like to deal with those cases?

```
library(data.table)
temp <- read.table(header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
                text = "Website Datetime    Rating
                        A       2012-10-9   10
                        A       2012-11-10  12
                        B       2011-10-9   5")
DT <- data.table(temp, key="Website")
DT
#    Website   Datetime Rating
# 1:       A  2012-10-9     10
# 2:       A 2012-11-10     12
# 3:       B  2011-10-9      5
DT[, list(Datetime = Datetime[which.max(Rating)], 
          Rating = max(Rating)), by = key(DT)]
#    Website   Datetime Rating
# 1:       A 2012-11-10     12
# 2:       B  2011-10-9      5
```

I would recommend that to get *better* answers, you might want to include information like how your datetime variable might factor into your aggregation, or whether it is possible for there to be more than one "max" value per group.

*If you want **all** the rows that match the max, the fix is easy:*

```
DT[, list(Time = Times[Rating == max(Rating)], 
          Rating = max(Rating)), by = key(DT)]
```

---

If you do just want the `Rating` column, there are *many* ways to go about this. Following the same steps as above to convert to a `data.table`, try:

```
DT[, list(Datetime = max(Rating)), by = key(DT)]
     Website Datetime
# 1:       A        4
# 2:       B        2
# 3:       C        5
```

Or, keeping the original "temp" `data.frame`, try `aggregate()`:

```
aggregate(Rating ~ Website, temp, max)
    Website Rating
# 1       A      4
# 2       B      2
# 3       C      5
```

---

Yet another approach, using `ave`:

```
temp[with(temp, Rating == ave(Rating, Website, FUN=max)), ]
```

Comment: Thank very much for your help. There can be multiple max values per category. For example the ratings in the example for A website might have been both 10.

Comment: @MichaelTsikerdekis, OK, so then what? As I mentioned, please update your *question* with a more realistic sample of data, also mentioning the types of bottlenecks you expect to encounter and how you would want to deal with them. For example, if there are multiple max values, do you want *all* rows matching the condition, or is the *first* row which matches the condition sufficient (as `which.max` will do).

Comment: I just updated the post and simplified the problem. That should probably make more clear and easier to solve. I tried to do it myself but so far failed miserably.

Comment: @MichaelTsikerdekis, so far as I can tell, my original answer still holds as applicable. Have you tried it?

Comment: Ananda indeed it works! Thank you very much and also thanks for the data.table idea. I've never used it before and it seems to be faster than data.frame.

Comment: WOW, I didn't even know there are these many options to do this.

Comment: @MichaelTsikerdekis, There are usually several approaches to solve problems in R. I would suggest sticking to `data.table` considering the size of your dataset, since it would probably be very fast for this type of data transformation. If any of the answers here help out, do be sure to upvote them or mark them as accepted ;)

Comment: I accepted the answer. Upvoting I can't do yet. I need 3 more posts.

Answer (score 3):

```
 do.call( rbind, lapply( split(temp, temp$Website) , 
                               function(d) d[ which.max(d$Rating), ] ) )
  Website             Datetime Rating
A       A 2006-07-28T03:52:26Z      4
B       B 2006-11-02T11:06:25Z      2
C       C 2007-06-19T06:56:08Z      5
```

Since your 'Datetime' variable does not appear to yet actually be either a Date or a datetime object, you should probably convert to a Date-object first.

`which.max` will pick the first item that is a maximum.

```
>  which.max(c(1,1,2,2))
[1] 3
```

So Ananda may not be correct in his warning in that regard. Datatable methods will certainly be more rapid and may also succeed if the machine memory is modest. The method above may make several copies along the way and data.table functions do not need to to as much copying.

Comment: DWin never gets my name right.... :( ... though I know *he* has a difficult name to get right too :)